# can't get loopback to install correctly...C++ error

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm trying to install loop back by following this guide on windows.

```
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SL/Installing+Node+and+StrongLoop+on+Windows
```

I've installed Python 2.7.1 x64, nodejs 64 and c++ runtime 2013 64 & 32. restarted my pc. And then when I run

```
npm install -g strongloop
```

I get this back:

```
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ronak.patel>npm install -g strongloop
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing strong-fork-syslog@1.2.3
/


> heapdump@0.3.6 install C:\Users\ronak.patel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\s
trongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\ronak.patel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\st
rong-supervisor\node_modules\heapdump>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\no
de-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\ronak.patel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\heapdump\build\binding.
sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ronak.patel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\no
de_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\heapdump
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok



> bufferutil@1.1.0 install C:\Users\ronak.patel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\strongloop\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

-
C:\Users\ronak.patel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\ws
\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Fi
les\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\no
de-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Answer (score 0):

`heapdump` (and `bufferutil`) in this case actually are optional dependencies, so if they don't compile/install, then the module (`strongloop`) will still be installed and should work just fine.

However if you want to ensure the optional dependencies get built/installed, you will need to have more than just the C++ runtime installed. You need at least Visual Studio Express (2012 or possibly newer, but 2012 should work for sure) installed to get the compiler, header files, etc. needed to compile addons.

Comment: For 2012, you'd want [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673).